# Where could I get straw for my pets in Lithuania?

Tags: pets, lithuania

I am from Germany. There you go in the pet shop and buy plastic bags with hay and straw from small (maybe 5 liters) up to big (maybe 30 liters).

Now we are in Lithuania and I could not find straw in any pet shop. I imagine I could look for horse shops but that straw will be too big for me to transport or store.

Where could I look for straw?

Comment: Did you ask in the pet shops where you might obtain straw?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Some could not speak english, the other send us to the next pet shop :(